# Stripping charaters out of email address to extract url

Tags: excel, email, url

I need to take a column of emails addresses and strip out @ and everything before it, and add "www." in order to get a list of web addresses. I found this formula: 
=RIGHT(C6,LEN(C6)-FIND("@",C6)) but I need it to get the url and the form each email and the return the results for EVERY email address and copy it into
a column

Answer (score 0):

If you have an email address in cell A1, put this in cell B1

```
=CONCATENATE("www.", RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("@",A1)))
```

Then drag the formula down the column until you reach the bottom row.